# Data won't show on fragment

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

Hey i'm beginner on parsing the data from mysql database using json and volley the problem is the data just want show on fragment and just show few second after that the list was gone, like in this picture [Trouble Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFVL9.png) and the list data won't get show in fragment which one i want it to be show on the fragments so

This is the code i used for show on fragments

**fragment.java**

```
public class KomentarFragment extends Fragment {
TextView nama,komen;
View v;
ArrayList<Komen> kmn = new ArrayList<>();
public static String url ="http://surveyclickon.000webhostapp.com/android_register_login/komen.php";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View kom =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_komentar,container,false);
    nama = kom.findViewById(R.id.nm2);
    komen = kom.findViewById(R.id.kmn2);

    new AsyncFetch().execute();

    return kom;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

    private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog.setMessage("Loading list ...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {

            // Enter URL address where your json file resides
            // Even you can make call to php file which returns json data
            url = new URL("http://surveyclickon.000webhostapp.com/android_register_login/back.php");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {

            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }
        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return (result.toString());

            } else {

                return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pDialog.dismiss();

        try{
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
            int code = object.getInt("refund");
            if(code == 0) {
                JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("refund");
                ArrayList<Refund> ref = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Refund refund = new Refund();
                    refund.setNm(jsonObject.getString("nama"));
                    refund.setNo(jsonObject.getString("no"));
                    refund.setAlam(jsonObject.getString("alamat"));
                    refund.setKode(jsonObject.getString("kode"));
                    refund.setAlas(jsonObject.getString("alasan"));
                    ref.add(refund);
                }
            }
        }catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

so how to made the data can be show off on the fragments? so after the storing data on database from database data will be show on the fragments

**fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:visibility="visible">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:text="Nama"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/nm2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/kmn2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nm2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Komentar"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Update the cod with complete fragment code.

Comment: i have update it with complete one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically didn't update the UI so you got nothing

```
public class KomentarFragment extends Fragment {
    List<Refund> refundList = new ArrayList<>();
    ....
}
```

then in your postExecute method

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Refund refund = new Refund();
            refund.setNm(jsonObject.getString("nama"));
            refund.setNo(jsonObject.getString("no"));
            refund.setAlam(jsonObject.getString("alamat"));
            refund.setKode(jsonObject.getString("kode"));
            refund.setAlas(jsonObject.getString("alasan"));
            refundList.add(refund);
        }
//Update the UI
//Store to the database
```

then you can update the UI with recyclerview or database wherever you need, you can do it also in the postExecute method

Comment: i have update but still like on image not on recyclerview